# Swift - findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock always returns nil

Tags: swift, parse-platform

My request always returns nil

```
    var query : PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
       query.whereKey("username", equalTo: searchForUser)
       query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (object, error) -> Void in
           if error != nil {
               self.user = object
           } else {
               println(error)
           }
    })
```

As result I want to have something that I can count to use it for tableView(numberOfRowsInTableView)

I think with my self.user = object it will not work?!

Comment: Where are you seeing the result be nil? Inside the block, where error != nil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` does not return anything immediately. It executes the query on a separate thread and then calls the block later. You'll need to use [these methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW53) (or just `reloadData`) to update the table view when your results change. (Make sure to do it on the main thread.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment - I think I am too new to swift to know exactly what I should do now. I don't know wich of theses methods you mean. I know how i can reloadData() but I don't know where or when?! After i called my function?

Comment: I would recommend reading [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html) to start with. The point is that your block `{(object,error) in ... }` will be executed *later*. At that time you need to update your model (e.g. `self.user`) and inform the table view that something has changed so it can display the result (`reloadData`).

Comment: It looks like the OP realizes that the completion handler is where the results will be available.  The first param of the completion handler ought to be an array, like this `objects: [AnyObject]?`